# WPF pass window as variable

Tags: c#, wpf, window

I have 4 windows.
1. SubjectMovies.xaml
2. SpecificMovies.xaml
3. SearchMovies.xaml
4. VideoPlayer.xaml

All the first 3 windows can open the forth one.
I want to know which one openend the fourth when the fourth is opened and store it in variable (to use it later - I want to use it like that: Sender(as Window).Show()), something like:

```
Window sender;
public VideoPlayer(Window s)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    sender = s;

}

private void GoBack()
{
    this.Hide();
    sender.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to set the [`Owner`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.owner.aspx) property of the `VideoPlayer` window. 
from each window you are opening it:

```
VideoPlayer vp = new VideoPlayer();
vp.Owner = this;
```

Inside `VideoPlayer` you can access it by `this.Owner`.

No need to recieve it as a parameter in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I recomment the ShowDialog on the child to achieve this, because the child should not be responsible for showing his parent.

example:

```
public void OpenVideoPlayer()
{
    VideoPlayer vp = new VideoPlayer();
    this.Hide();
    vp.ShowDialog();
    this.Show();
}
```

This way the child doesn't depend on a parent. Also if you don't want to hide the parent, but instead to minimize it, the parent is in control of that.

With events:

```
public void OpenVideoPlayer()
{
    VideoPlayer vp = new VideoPlayer();
    vp.Closed += vp_Closed;
    this.Hide();
    vp.Show();
}

void wnd_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Show();
}
```

Comment: This way though the parent won't be accessible until the child window is closed

Comment: The parent shouldn't be directly accessed by the child. if you want to exchange some information to the parent, you should use events. So even if you want the child to display the parent. It should call an event, something like: RequestShowParent event, to notify the parent form to show itself.

Comment: I want to access the parent from the child without to create events/functions in all the 3 windows